# Bulk change image extension

Tags: magento-1.9, image

After ages I have decided to optimize the images on my store, to do so I have download the `media` folder and `compressed all the images with Caesium leaving the original folder structure.`
The first run left the extension unchanged, I have obtained a good file size reduction, but I have also tried to change the extension to see if any improvements can be obtained(if the size is bigger than the original, then the image is skipped): the result was a further reduction of 44Mb.

**Now my problem/doubt is how can I upload back all the images and register the extension change?** My first guess is to edit the table that stores these information, but `I have no idea how the Magento framework store/manage these data.` Is it better to avoid this kind of procedure?

Comment: If the images name are same then my guess is just uploading those back to media folder will work. By the way is it Magento1 or Magento2.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Sorry, I have added the tag for `magento 1.9`, the image management works independently from the extension of the image?

Comment: If names are still same then just put the media folder back. You dont have to do any changes in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento stores images in the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table. The `value` field should have your image name.
You can just run the query

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
SET
    value = REPLACE(value, '.old_ext', '.new_ext')
```

but please backup first.

Comment: You surely know better but does he need to run this query if all images name are unchanged.

Comment: from what I understood the file extension was changed. If I understood wrong, then the query is not needed.